# unserialize data while exporting csv

Tags: php, excel, excel-formula, export-to-csv

is there any formula in excel or any other way to unserialize php data which calls from database while exporting csv file??

I actually created a csv file successfully but their is serialized data so i want to make it unserialized

Comment: Please clarify where you would like to have the unserialize happen. While outputing the CSV in php, or in Excel?

Comment: By 'serialized' data, do you mean data that's been passed through `serialize()`, or just a set of columns that are concatenated into one column?

Comment: Daren outputing the csv in excel & halfer yes passed by php serialized method & stored in datbase & i am retrieving it from database...while creating exporting csv...

It thing will be some formula thing will apply on excell like baptme below answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Excel you can use text to columns in Data, then choose Delimited and the choose , or ; as a separator depending on the format of your csv.

If you want to export from database to a spreadsheet format regulary like i do, look at http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

mobi001:

The best way of working with serialized date is using JSON:

```
<?php
$arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);

echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

The above example will output: {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}

You can use the oposite function "json_decode" in order to retrieve the original array...

Answer (score 0):

i think i have to make a bridge for this..to make unserialize data as there in no such query in sql to unserilize it on mysql..or i donot found any formula of excell which effect on it..

http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

actually i was using a plugin which only allow to put sql queries & excell formula in their backend option so now i have to customize it